# AWS Beanstalk to RDS issues with DataNucleus

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, datanucleus

I am trying to run a JSP file deployed to Amazon's Beanstalk, which uses DataNucleus to connect to RDS, and am getting the following error:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://mydbblahblah.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://bmydbblahblah.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:640)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
```

Now I have the MySQL connector files in the classpath (it is at `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar`, so this should work.

I have also confirmed that if I remove the library from there, I get the "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found on CLASSPATH" error.

Here is what my `datanucleus.properties` file looks like this:

```
javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass=org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory

javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://bmydbblahblah.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb
#javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=user
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=pwnothere
```

All of this works on my local Tomcat connecting to RDS. It only fails when running on Beanstalk.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: NO idea about your issue, other than trying the jdbc driver in different locations, but just wondered if you'd have time to document something about using DataNucleus on Beanstalk and provide it back to the DataNucleus project? Thx

Comment: Until it is working, there is nothing to document. DataNucleus is a fantastic idea, but getting it to work, and work consistently, is never easy.

Comment: Needless to say it works for us on all platforms we've provided it for, and have no reported issue preventing its use on those. Onus is always on people to define their problem, and optionally, contribute to it.

Comment: That is JDBC that is looking for the driver and not finding it, not DataNucleus. So you ought to have looked at registration of the driver and where you put it in the CLASSPATH and check that it is being registered

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So we downgraded to DataNucleus 2.0 without any other changes, and the issue disappeared. Sad, but it worked. I cannot recommend newer versions of DataNucleus with MySQL.

Comment: Post from someone who took the time to debug the Beanstalk product (problem was nothing to do with DataNucleus) http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7643

Answer (score 0):

I [almost] resolved this issue using the following procedure:
http://www.cubehouse.org/blog/2011/03/04/using-rds-aws-mysql-on-an-elastic-beanstalk-java-tomcat-server-with-ec2-security-permissions/

With the addition that your EC2 Security Group needs a rule set for port 3306.
Sadly, this code can read but not write.

Comment: Yeah, I have heard of others having this issue with DataNucleus even as far back as version 2.2.1. They downgraded back to 2.0 to get it working again. We will see if anyone else has a solution.

Comment: As said above, JDBC is the thing not finding the JDBC driver, so focus your thinking on the JDBC registration mechanism